# How to create JavaScript object outside of a window object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browser, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to create a js object that is not under the window object? If yes, then how?
There is a different [ongoing discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59121377/where-exactly-the-virtual-dom-is-stored?noredirect=1#comment104480761_59121377) when I'm trying to understand the location of `_internalRoot` object created by ReactRoot() constructor. Good people say that most probably it's not under the `window` object.

I was sure that we could not create an object outside of a window object.

Comment: You mean global object?

Comment: Only global variables (including top level variables declared with `var`) are implicitly added to `window`. A variable declared with `let` or `const` or a variable inside a function, E.G. `function ReactRoot ( ) { var _internalRoot = { }; }` is not added to `window`.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. The one last thing that bothers is that when I create an object like this, I can's see the "ReactRoot" on the list of constructors in a heap snapshot (chrome).

Answer (score 2):

Just create the object in a local variable:

```
function example() {
    var demo = {};
}
example();
```

Even if `example` is a global variable and somehow tied to `window`, the `demo` variable is not.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. The one last thing that bothers me is that when I create an object inside a "ReactRoot" function, I can't see the "ReactRoot" on the list of constructors in a heap snapshot (chrome).

Comment: Well, the object was not constructed through `demoObject = new ReactRoot`, but just *inside* a `ReactRoot` function.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is, create an immediately executing function(IIFE) and create your object in it.

```
(function() {
  var yourObject = {};
})();
```

more details on IIFE is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE